# Django API and Front-End Separation Issues

Tags: python, django, angular, apache, django-rest-framework

I'm starting to learn Django Rest Framework for my back-end and using Angular 4 for the front-end. I've read that some people are separating the two via GIT for scalability and team separation among other things, so I thought I would follow that idea and also try to separate the in two separate directories.

I have installed Django on a Centos7 box with Apache. (the webserver is on my home network and is port-forwarded through my home router) The Django files are in one directory and my Angular files are in a separate directory.

There are many other projects on the server so I'm not running Django on the root. An example url would be `http://0.0.0.0/project1` I also have `http://0.0.0.0/project2` and etc... This Django project is `http://0.0.0.0/myproject/api` which I can access and run just fine. But, when I put my front-end code in the front-end directory (`http://0.0.0.0/myproject/front_end`) and try to access it I get a Django 404 error. (I have debug=True on)

My goal is to have my api accessed like `http://0.0.0.0/myproject/api/example` and front-end accessed using `http://0.0.0.0/myproject`. I may have to use virtual hosts to make that happen, but I'm not sure.

What I cannot figure out is why is there a 404 when my Django project is in a different folder? How can I run my Angular 4 project from the front_end directory?

## Directory Structure

```
/var/www/html/myproject
├── api
│   ├── core (Django files)
│   ├── etc... 
└── front_end
    ├── app (Angular 4 files)
    ├── etc...
```

## Urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movie', views.MovieViewSet, 'movie')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/login', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/refresh/token/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/verify/token/', verify_jwt_token),
]
```

## httpd.conf

I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe something here is causing the issue:

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/myproject/api/core/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/api/core/static/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/api/core/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/var/www/html/myproject/api/
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias /myproject /var/www/html/myproject/api/core/wsgi.py
```

Note, I'm very new to Django so I'm not sure what code would be helpful to post. Let me know what I should post and I'll edit my post.

Comment: After typing all this out and visually looking at it I figured it out. I'll answer this with what I did to fix it for anyone who needs it.